# Does polymorphism exist in QML?

Tags: qt, pointers, reference, polymorphism, qml

Does polymorphism and/or object pointers exist in QML? I have a class `A` that has five members of different classes of which exactly one is visible at any given moment. I also have properties in `A` that depend on properties in the visible member (which are called the same things in all members).

Currently, I'm calculating every such property in `A` using the following strategy:

```
import QtQuick 2.7

Rectangle {
    property int a: member1.visible ? member1.alpha + member1.beta :
                    member2.visible ? member2.alpha + member2.beta :
                    member3.visible ? member3.alpha + member3.beta :
                    member4.visible ? member4.alpha + member4.beta :
                    member5.visible ? member5.alpha + member5.beta :
                    0

    property int b: member1.visible ? member1.gamma * member1.delta :
                    member2.visible ? member2.gamma * member2.delta :
                    member3.visible ? member3.gamma * member3.delta :
                    member4.visible ? member4.gamma * member4.delta :
                    member5.visible ? member5.gamma * member5.delta :
                    0

    // Exactly one of these members have its visible-property set to true
    MySubClass1 {id: member1}
    MySubClass2 {id: member2}
    MySubClass3 {id: member3}
    MySubClass4 {id: member4}
    MySubClass5 {id: member5}
}
```

which feels both like it's using more code than necessary, and like it's not very maintenance friendly both since it's easy to make an error and since I have to update the expressions for all properties in A if I want to add or remove a member.

Ideally (comming from a background of doing a lot of C++ programming), I would like to be able to do something like this:

```
import QtQuick 2.7

Rectangle {
    property <property-type> visibleMember:
        member1.visible ? member1 :
        member2.visible ? member2 :
        member3.visible ? member3 :
        member4.visible ? member4 :
        member5.visible ? member5 :
        0  // Shouldn't happen

    property int a: visibleMember.alpha + visibleMember.beta
    property int b: visibleMember.gamma * visibleMember.delta

    MySubClass1 {id: member1}
    MySubClass2 {id: member2}
    MySubClass3 {id: member3}
    MySubClass4 {id: member4}
    MySubClass5 {id: member5}
}
```

in order to reduce the amount of code needed to be written and increase the maintainability, where `visibleMember` would then be a pointer or some kind of reference to an object. Or perhaps even:

```
import QtQuick 2.7

Rectangle {
    property <property-type> visibleMember: NULL

    property int a: visibleMember !== NULL ? visibleMember.alpha + visibleMember.beta : 0
    property int b: visibleMember !== NULL ? visibleMember.gamma * visibleMember.delta : 0
}
```

and set `visibleMember` from outside the class (for example by its parent) and in that way be able to create objects dynamically (if that is possible) which are then assigned to `visibleMember`, instead of having all possible objects that can be assigned to `visibleMember` existing as latent members in `A`.

However, I'm not sure what `<property-type>` would be, or whether you can assign an object pointer to `visibleMember` like this (i.e. whether object pointers/references exist), which can then be checked to see whether it is a `NULL` pointer. Is at least somethng of what I'm trying to do possible to achieve in some way?

Comment: Why was my question downvoted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you need to do that? It seems like you are abusing the QML language and you will surely run into performance issues.

Please spend some time trying to understand the QML language and how it differs from C++.

First note that

```
Rectangle {

    MySubClass1 {id: member1}
    MySubClass2 {id: member2}
}
```

is absolutely not equivalent to:

```
struct MyStruct: public Rectangle
{
    MySubClass1 member1;
    MySubClass2 member2;
}
```

but it is rather something like that:

```
struct MyStruct: public Rectangle
{
    MyStruct()
    {
        children.insert("member1", new MySubClass1);
        children.insert("member2", new MySubClass2);
    }
    map<string, void *> children;
}
```

If you need only on member at a given time, you can do something like that:

```
// MyComponent.qml
Rectangle {
    id: root
    property var visibleMember: InitialMember{} // If you can, replace var by the closest fitting data type

    property int a: visibleMember.alpha + visibleMember.beta
    property int b: visibleMember.gamma * visibleMember.delta

    function change1() {
        visibleMember.destroy();
        var component = Qt.createComponent("MySubClass1.qml");
        var object = component.createObject(root);
        visibleMember = object;
    }

    function change2() {
        visibleMember.destroy();
        var object = Qt.createQmlObject('import QtQuick 2.0; MySubClass2 {}', root);
        visibleMember = object;
    }
}
```

And you can also set `visibleMember` from outside either statically or dynamically:

```
MyComponent { // Assumming the code above is in MyComponent.qml
    visibleMember: SomethingElse {}
}
```

*Note:* If this is the way `MyComponent` is supposed to be used, the you can remove `change1()`, `change2()` and even maybe `InitialMember{}` from `MyComponent.qml`.

### Edit

Same as above but using `Loader` instead of `Qt.createComponent()`

```
Rectangle {
    id: root
    property var visibleMember: loader.item // If you can replace var by the closest fitting data type
    property alias source: loader.source // If you want to expose the loader source

    property int a: visibleMember.alpha + visibleMember.beta
    property int b: visibleMember.gamma * visibleMember.delta

    function change1() {
        loader.source = "MySubClass1.qml";
    }

    function change2() {
        loader.source = "MySubClass2.qml";
    }

    Loader {
        id: loader
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually I like his *declarative approach* better than doing everything with JS... And your code doesn't come close to beeing equivalent, as internal changes are lost once you create/destroy/recreate the objects. They might miss signals. *IF* destruction would be ok, QML offers enough solutions for dynamically but still declarativly creating objects.

Comment: @derM Look at penultimate paragraph of the question. It does not seem like having an instance of each subclass is the primary goal, but rather  consequence of not understanding QML. Now if you only need one instance at a given time, I don't see the point in creating declaratively an instance of each subclass and so much binding in `visibleMember`, it is a loss of time and resources.

Comment: Yeah, ok - you are right, that dynamic instantiation might be ok for him. But there are still some things bad in your code: **1.** You use `var` as property type, which is unlikely the closest fitting base type. **2.** The `InitialMember{}` will leak when you call `change`, as it is indestructible. **3.** You use JS for dynamic object instantiation instead of the QML dynamic instantiators like `Loader` et. al. **4.** `InitialMember{}` will leak as it wont be ignored. It will be constructed. Then `SomethingElse` will be constructed and bound to the property. `InitalMember` wont be  destroyed.

Comment: You can destroy `InitialMember{}` by calling `destroy()`, but anyway it is not a leak: when `MyComponent` will be destroyed any "leaked" `InitialMember` will be destroyed.

Comment: Intresting. I am pretty sure I got a "Error: Invalid attempt to destroy() an indestructible object." error, when I created them like that, at a point where I didn't even started combining QML with C++. But I can't reproduce it. So either I did something different, or it was a bug that is now fixed. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Nice! I really like the `Loader` solution. I found I could even set the loader source declarativelly, as derM pointed out. I don't know if setting it declarativelly is better than setting it imperativelly, though, except from looking "cleaner" in my opinion.

Comment: In one of my members, I have a slot called `onVisibleChanged` which is triggered when the member becomes visible. This slot is not triggered any more, since I don't change the visibility any more, but rather create and destroy objects dynamically. Is there some way I can make this slot become triggered when the object is created instead of when its visibility is changed?

Comment: I found it. The slot I was looking for was `Component.onCompleted`.

Answer (score 1):

If all classes inherit the same base class, let's say `QtObject` you can easily use that as the property type.

You can still access properties that would not be existent in the base class, as the concrete objects keep their original meta information.
This meta information then is used to evaluate the bindings.

If you try to access a property that is not defined in the concrete object where you want to access it, it will evaluate to `undefined`. If you try to access a subproperty this would throw warning.

If you don't have any common baseclass, because it might also be a `string` or a `int` you can use  `var` as data type for the property.

> For performance reasons it is advisable to use the closest fitting/possible data type. If the data type used for the property already features the properties that you want to access in it, the bindings can be optimized.

---

*Lets say our base class is `MyBaseClass`, then you could write:*

```
import QtQuick 2.7

Rectangle {
    property MyBaseClass visibleMember:
        member1.visible ? member1 :
        member2.visible ? member2 :
        member3.visible ? member3 :
        member4.visible ? member4 :
        member5.visible ? member5 :
        null  // Shouldn't happen

    property int a: visibleMember.alpha + visibleMember.beta
    property int b: visibleMember.gamma * visibleMember.delta

    MySubClass1 {id: member1}
    MySubClass2 {id: member2}
    MySubClass3 {id: member3}
    MySubClass4 {id: member4}
    MySubClass5 {id: member5}
}
```

If that base class also has the properties `alpha, beta, gamma, delta` predefined, the bindings for `a` and `b` might be optimized.

---

Of course you can also just set that property from the outside, as you have exposed it in the root node of the component.